# how can I do the action based on user input in python

Tags: python, input, chatbot

I have this code

```
phrase = input("Enter your message: ")

if 'hello' in phrase:
  print('Hello, Human')
if 'what is your favorite color' in phrase:
  print("It's blue")
else:
  print('unavailable')
```

how can it reply based on user like if he say hello and then what is your favorite color it will reply hello then it's blue like below:

```
Enter your message: hello, what is your favorite color
Hello, Human
It's blue
```

and that's okay but what if I want to automatically change like if he say what is your favorite color and then hello it will reply it's blue and then hello so the output should like this:

```
Enter your message: what is your favorite color, hello
It's blue
Hello, Human
```

but not like this:

```
Enter your message: what is your favorite color, hello
Hello, Human
It's blue
```

Comment: It seems that you need to know the order of these two patterns in `phrase`. You can use `pat1_idx = phase.find("hello")` and `pat2_idx = phrase.find("what is your favorite color")`. The return value of `phrase.find(pattern)` can help you determine whether the pattern exists and where it starts.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit too unspecific.. please specify it a bit more.

For the favorite color, since the user might ask something like "what's your favorite color", your program won't respond with blue because it's different from "what is your favorite color", so just have the program check for "favorite color".

```
phrase = input("Enter your message: ")

if 'hello' in phrase:
  print('Hello, Human')
elif 'favorite color' in phrase:
  print("It's blue")
else:
  print('unavailable')
```

Comment: No I can't explain it but If I ask you hello and then what is your favorite color you will answer me hello and then your favorite color and if I ask you what is your favorite color and then hello you answer by your favorite color and then hello I want to do the same thing in the code like the user choose the logic of the code

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and output? Like the user inputs something and what should come out.

Comment: Enter your message: hello, what is your favorite color

Answer (score 0):

```
phrase = input("Enter your message: ")

if 'hello' in phrase:
  print('Hello, Human')
  phrase1 = input('Enter your message: ')
  if phrase1 == 'what is your favorite color':
    print('its blue')
elif 'what is your favorite color' in phrase:
  print("It's blue")
  phrase2 = input('Enter your message: ')
  if phrase2 == 'hello':
    print('hello human')
else:
  print('unavailable')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).